# Can't figure out how to continuously keep an app running, without having to refresh to reset all parameters correctly

Tags: javascript

```
const qwerty = document.querySelector("#qwerty");
let phrase = document.querySelector("#phrase");
let missed =  0;
const reset = document.querySelector(".btn__reset");
const startScreen = document.querySelector(".start");
let myPhrase ;
const phrases = [
"Knowledge comes but wisdom lingers",
"In the end everything is a gag",
"Fortune favors the brave",
"A joke is a very serious thing",
"Where there is love there is life"
];
const ul = document.querySelector("ul");
let listItems = [];
let guessedListItems = [];
let letterArray = [];
const overlay = document.querySelector("#overlay")
const buttons = document.querySelectorAll("button")
const hearts = document.querySelectorAll(".tries")

reset.addEventListener("click", () => {
    startScreen.style.display = "none";
});

function getRandomPhraseAsArray (arr) {
    //picks random number from 0-4 for array index
    let num = Math.floor(5 * Math.random());
    //splits that string of specified index into array of letters
    myPhrase =  arr[num].split("");
    console.log(myPhrase);
    //returns that new array of letters in a variable called myPhrase
    return myPhrase;
}

function addPhraseToDisplay(myPhrase){
  for (let i = 0 ; i < myPhrase.length ; i++ ){
    //creates a new list item  elemetn
    const li = document.createElement("li");
//for each letter/index in array, a new list item is created
    li.textContent += myPhrase[i];
    //appends those elements to the ul
       ul.appendChild(li);
       listItems.push(li);
      // if the letter at index "i" is an empty string, " " 
      // give it the specified class
     if (myPhrase[i] == " "){
         li.classList.add("space");
         //if element is a ., no class
        //change this to regex to filter out .
     } else if (myPhrase[i] == "." || myPhrase[i] == ","){
            li.classList.add("show");
            li.classList.add("letter");
     }
     //if letter, add class name letter
     else {
        li.classList.add("letter");
     }
  }
  //return the list items of the letters
  return myPhrase;
}

function checkLetter(clickedLetter) {

  let letterFound = false;
    if (clickedLetter.tagName == "BUTTON"){
        clickedLetter.className = "chosen";
        clickedLetter.setAttribute("disabled", "true");
        const li = document.querySelectorAll(".letter");
        for (let i = 0 ; i < li.length ; i++){
            if (clickedLetter.textContent.toLowerCase() == li[i].textContent.toLowerCase()){
        li[i].classList.add("show");
        letterFound = true;
            } 
        }
  }

  if (letterFound) {
        return clickedLetter.textContent.toLowerCase();
  }
  else {
    return null;
  } 
}

function checkWin() {
  const h2 =  document.querySelector("h2");
  function contains (item){
        return item.classList.contains("show");
    }
    if(missed === 5){
         h2.textContent = "You lose, try again!";
         startScreen.style.display = "block";
         startScreen.classList.add("lose");
         reset.textContent = "New Game?";
         newGame();
        }
    else if (letterArray.every(contains)){
        startScreen.style.display = "block";
        startScreen.classList.add("win");
        h2.textContent = "You Win!";
        reset.textContent = "New Game?";
        newGame();      
    }   
}

function newGame(){
     missed = 0;
     myPhrase = [];
     for (let i = 0 ; i < listItems.length ; i++) {
            ul.firstElementChild.remove();
        }
    listItems.length = 0
    for (let i = 0 ; i < buttons.length ; i++){
        if (buttons[i].disabled ==  true) {
            buttons[i].disabled = false;
            buttons[i].classList.remove("chosen");
        }    
    }
    const  ol = document.querySelector("ol")
        for (let i = 0 ; i < hearts.length ; i++){
        ol.appendChild(hearts[i]);
        }
    console.log(missed)
    getRandomPhraseAsArray(phrases);
    addPhraseToDisplay(myPhrase);
}

qwerty.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
        for (let i = 0 ; i < listItems.length ; i++){
         if (listItems[i].classList.contains("space")){
            //guessedListItems now only contain spaces
             guessedListItems.push(listItems[i]);
        }
        else if (listItems[i].classList.contains("letter")){
            //lettersArray  now only contains letters
             letterArray.push(listItems[i]);
        }   
    }
}, {once: true});

qwerty.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
  const clickedLetter = e.target;
  if (clickedLetter.tagName == "DIV"){
    //does not remove heart if user clicks on area around keyboard
         return false
  }
  checkLetter(clickedLetter);
  console.log(checkLetter(clickedLetter));
  if (checkLetter(clickedLetter)  == null){
    missed+=1;
    const ol = document.querySelector("ol");
    const tries = document.querySelectorAll(".tries");
    ul.children ;
    ol.removeChild(tries[0]);
    checkWin();
  }
  else {
    checkWin();
  }
});

getRandomPhraseAsArray(phrases);
addPhraseToDisplay(myPhrase);
```

https://jsfiddle.net/qo8gp5b9/

Here is a jfiddle demo this simple game I wrote

The problem is, I cannot seem to make the game "reset" correctly after the first go around. After the player either guesses correctly or loses all of their lives, they are prompted with a window to start a new game. However,  I am able to reset everything back to how it initially was after you first load the page, EXCEPT the program continuously shows the "win" screen after the first guess on the second go around. I cannot seem to figure out where in my code to bug is happening. Can someone help me out? I am aware my code snippet is long, but I would really appreciate it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a cleaned and functioning version of your game.
I changed quite a few small things, but the main error you were experiencing in the end was:

What happens inside the `click` listener that you created using the `{ once: true }` option needs to happen for every new game and not only once in the lifetime of the page. I moved the logic into the `addPhraseToDisplay()` function.

```js
const qwerty = document.querySelector("#qwerty");
const phrase = document.querySelector("#phrase");
const overlay = document.querySelector("#overlay")
const reset = document.querySelector(".btn__reset");
const startScreen = document.querySelector(".start");
const phraseList = document.querySelector("ul");
const buttons = document.querySelectorAll("button")
const heartsList = document.querySelector("ol")
const hearts = document.querySelectorAll(".tries")

const phrases = [
  "Knowledge comes but wisdom lingers",
  "In the end everything is a gag",
  "Fortune favors the brave",
  "A joke is a very serious thing",
  "Where there is love there is life"
];

let currentPhrase;
let missed = 0;
let listItems = [];
let guessedListItems = [];
let letterArray = [];

function setRandomPhraseAsArray() {
  let num = Math.floor(5 * Math.random());

  currentPhrase = phrases[num].split("");
}

function addPhraseToDisplay() {
  for (let i = 0; i < currentPhrase.length; i++) {
    const li = document.createElement("li");
    li.textContent += currentPhrase[i];
    phraseList.appendChild(li);
    listItems.push(li);

    if (currentPhrase[i] == " ") {
      li.classList.add("space");
      guessedListItems.push(li);
    } else if (currentPhrase[i] == "." || currentPhrase[i] == ",") {
      li.classList.add("show");
      li.classList.add("letter");
    } else {
      li.classList.add("letter");
      letterArray.push(li);
    }
  }
}

function checkLetter(clickedLetter) {
  let letterFound = false;

  if (clickedLetter.tagName == "BUTTON") {
    clickedLetter.className = "chosen";
    clickedLetter.setAttribute("disabled", "true");
    const li = document.querySelectorAll(".letter");
    for (let i = 0; i < li.length; i++) {
      if (clickedLetter.textContent.toLowerCase() == li[i].textContent.toLowerCase()) {
        li[i].classList.add("show");
        letterFound = true;
      }
    }
  }

  if (letterFound) {
    return clickedLetter.textContent.toLowerCase();
  } else {
    return null;
  }
}

function checkWin() {
  const h2 = document.querySelector("h2");

  function contains(item) {
    return item.classList.contains("show");
  }

  if (missed === 5) {
    h2.textContent = "You lose, try again!";
    startScreen.classList.add("lose");
    startScreen.style.display = "block";
    reset.textContent = "New Game?";
  } else if (letterArray.every(contains)) {
    startScreen.classList.add("win");
    h2.textContent = "You Win!";
    startScreen.style.display = "block";
    reset.textContent = "New Game?";
  }
}

function newGame() {
  while (phraseList.firstChild) {
    phraseList.removeChild(phraseList.firstChild);
  }

  for (let i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++) {
    if (buttons[i].disabled == true) {
      buttons[i].disabled = false;
      buttons[i].classList.remove("chosen");
    }
  }

  for (let i = 0; i < hearts.length; i++) {
    heartsList.appendChild(hearts[i]);
  }

  missed = 0;
  myPhrase = [];

  listItems = [];
  guessedListItems = [];
  letterArray = [];

  setRandomPhraseAsArray();
  addPhraseToDisplay();
}

qwerty.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
  const clickedLetter = e.target;

  if (clickedLetter.tagName == "DIV") {
    return false
  }

  if (null === checkLetter(clickedLetter)) {
    missed += 1;
    heartsList.removeChild(heartsList.firstChild);
  }

  checkWin();
});

reset.addEventListener("click", function() {
  newGame();
  startScreen.style.display = "none";
});

newGame();
```

```css
/* Main styles */

@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,700&Roboto:300');
:root {
  --color-win: #78CF82;
  --color-lose: #D94545;
  --color-start: #5b85b7;
  --color-neutral: #445069;
  --color-neutral-light: #D2D2D2;
  --color-keys: #37474F;
  --color-keys-light: #E5E5E5;
  --font-size-large: 60px;
  --font-size-medium: 20px;
  --transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
}


/* main */

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  justify-content: space-evenly;
  flex-direction: column;
  display: flex;
  height: 100vh;
}

li,
ol,
ul {
  padding: 0;
  display: inline-block;
}

h2 {
  margin: 0;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  font-size: var(--font-size-large);
}

button {
  margin: 6px;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
  padding: 0.5rem 1rem;
  color: var(--color-keys);
  font-size: var(--font-size-medium);
  background-color: var(--color-keys-light);
  border-radius: 5px;
  -webkit-transition: var(--transition);
  -o-transition: var(--transition);
  transition: var(--transition);
}

.main-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-around;
  height: 100%;
  max-height: 900px;
  text-align: center;
}

.section {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 10px;
}


/* Title */

.header {
  color: var(--color-start);
}


/* Phrase */

.letter {
  font-size: var(--font-size-medium);
  height: 65px;
  width: 65px;
  padding: 20px 1px 0 1px;
  margin-right: 2px;
  color: transparent;
  background: var(--color-neutral-light);
  border-radius: 5px;
  transition: background-color 1s ease, color 1s ease;
}

.space {
  width: 15px;
}

.show {
  color: #000;
  background-color: #76CE82;
}


/* Keyboard */

.keyrow {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.chosen {
  background: var(--color-neutral);
  border-radius: 5px;
  font-size: var(--font-size-medium);
  color: #FFFFFF;
}

.btn__reset {
  padding: 8px;
  margin: 50px auto;
  background: #FFFFFF;
  border-radius: 5px;
  font-size: var(--font-size-medium);
}


/* Overlay */

#overlay {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  position: fixed;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  justify-content: center;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

.title {
  color: #FFF;
}

.start {
  background-color: var(--color-start);
}

.start a {
  color: var(--color-win);
}

.win {
  background-color: var(--color-win);
}

.win a {
  color: var(--color-win);
}

.lose {
  background-color: var(--color-lose);
}

.lose a {
  color: var(--color-lose);
}

.tries {
  margin-left: 5px;
  margin-right: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="main-container">
  <div id="overlay" class="start">
    <h2 class="title">Wheel of Success</h2>
    <a class="btn__reset">Start Game</a>
  </div>
  <div id="banner" class="section">
    <h2 class="header">Wheel of Success</h2>
  </div>

  <div id="phrase" class="section">
    <ul></ul>
  </div>
  <div id="qwerty" class="section">
    <div class="keyrow">
      <button>q</button><button>w</button><button>e</button><button>r</button><button>t</button><button>y</button><button>u</button><button>i</button><button>o</button><button>p</button>
    </div>
    <div class="keyrow">
      <button>a</button><button>s</button><button>d</button><button>f</button><button>g</button><button>h</button><button>j</button><button>k</button><button>l</button>
    </div>
    <div class="keyrow">
      <button>z</button><button>x</button><button>c</button><button>v</button><button>b</button><button>n</button><button>m</button>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div id="scoreboard" class="section">
    <ol>
      <li class="tries">
        <svg aria-hidden="true" focusable="false" data-prefix="fas" data-icon="heart" role="img" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 512 512" width="30"><path fill="blue" d="M462.3 62.6C407.5 15.9 326 24.3 275.7 76.2L256 96.5l-19.7-20.3C186.1 24.3 104.5 15.9 49.7 62.6c-62.8 53.6-66.1 149.8-9.9 207.9l193.5 199.8c12.5 12.9 32.8 12.9 45.3 0l193.5-199.8c56.3-58.1 53-154.3-9.8-207.9z" class=""></path></svg>
      </li>
      <li class="tries">
        <svg aria-hidden="true" focusable="false" data-prefix="fas" data-icon="heart" role="img" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 512 512" width="30"><path fill="blue" d="M462.3 62.6C407.5 15.9 326 24.3 275.7 76.2L256 96.5l-19.7-20.3C186.1 24.3 104.5 15.9 49.7 62.6c-62.8 53.6-66.1 149.8-9.9 207.9l193.5 199.8c12.5 12.9 32.8 12.9 45.3 0l193.5-199.8c56.3-58.1 53-154.3-9.8-207.9z" class=""></path></svg>
      </li>
      <li class="tries">
        <svg aria-hidden="true" focusable="false" data-prefix="fas" data-icon="heart" role="img" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 512 512" width="30"><path fill="blue" d="M462.3 62.6C407.5 15.9 326 24.3 275.7 76.2L256 96.5l-19.7-20.3C186.1 24.3 104.5 15.9 49.7 62.6c-62.8 53.6-66.1 149.8-9.9 207.9l193.5 199.8c12.5 12.9 32.8 12.9 45.3 0l193.5-199.8c56.3-58.1 53-154.3-9.8-207.9z" class=""></path></svg>
      </li>
      <li class="tries">
        <svg aria-hidden="true" focusable="false" data-prefix="fas" data-icon="heart" role="img" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 512 512" width="30"><path fill="blue" d="M462.3 62.6C407.5 15.9 326 24.3 275.7 76.2L256 96.5l-19.7-20.3C186.1 24.3 104.5 15.9 49.7 62.6c-62.8 53.6-66.1 149.8-9.9 207.9l193.5 199.8c12.5 12.9 32.8 12.9 45.3 0l193.5-199.8c56.3-58.1 53-154.3-9.8-207.9z" class=""></path></svg>
      </li>
      <li class="tries">
        <svg aria-hidden="true" focusable="false" data-prefix="fas" data-icon="heart" role="img" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 512 512" width="30"><path fill="blue" d="M462.3 62.6C407.5 15.9 326 24.3 275.7 76.2L256 96.5l-19.7-20.3C186.1 24.3 104.5 15.9 49.7 62.6c-62.8 53.6-66.1 149.8-9.9 207.9l193.5 199.8c12.5 12.9 32.8 12.9 45.3 0l193.5-199.8c56.3-58.1 53-154.3-9.8-207.9z" class=""></path></svg>
      </li>
    </ol>
  </div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/app.js"></script>
```

Comment: you're awesome! thanks so much for the help and thanks for cleaning that up for me. Really appreciate it!